# Laravel - Show Data From Database With @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I'm trying to show data in table format from my DB. `thead` shows up in the table, but the `tbody` won't show up. I think, the problem is in the `@foreach` function. Because, I have tried to type something outside the `@foreach` function, and it shows up. And, I have tried to move the `@foreach` inside `<tr>`, but the result is just the same. Here's a part of my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border="1px solid black">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Created At</td>
            <td>Updated At</td>
            <td>Date of birth</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($student as $key => $value)
        <!--$student is imported from another file,
        with this function: $student = Student::all()-->
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->updated_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->dob}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->gender}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{URL::to('student/' . $value->id)
                }}">Show</a> | 
                <a href="{{URL::to('student/' . $value->id)
                    .'/edit'}}">Edit</a> |
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo url('/')
                    ."/student/".$value->id."/delete";?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="
                        {!!csrf_token() !!}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class=
                                "btn btn-warning">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of error you get for this?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I don't get any errors, it's just the data from DB won't show up

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud This is the code: `public function index()
    {
        $student = Student::all();
        return view('student.index', compact('student'));
    }` What is `var_dump`? Where should I put it?

Comment: add anyone of this before foreach loop `<?php dd($student); ?>` or  `<?php var_dump($student); ?>` and let me know the output.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I add the first one, and this shows up before the table: `Collection {#138 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: Have get the database items in this array value?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud If you want to answer again, please just answer in answer column, so it can be more readable. Thanks

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I don't understand

Comment: Ok, I think you need to improve Basic PHP then try with laravel.If you dont know what is `var_dump()` then i have doubt about in PHP.I am asking for solve this problem.Please increase your skill in Raw PHP first.Thanks :)

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I'm a student, & laravel is what my teacher teaches me, so I can say no to that :(

Comment: Can you show me your controller code from where you called this view?

Comment: @BasharNozibulla Please read the comments above. I have add it in my comments, as an answer to ChoncholMahmud comments

Comment: comment out the line where you return the view. now after that add this line `return $student;` and see if you got any json response in return.

Comment: @BasharNozibulla  
When I add `return $student`, it shows up empty array brackets. But, I already have 10 data in my DB

Comment: @BasharNozibulla I have found the mistake. Thanks

Comment: If you got help from any of my comment then please don't forget to give an up vote for that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, If you are using blade file you can use {{ }} in place of ;

First you can check $student has data or not.
In your controller just before returning view you can do

```
return $student;
```

Refresh your page. If data is coming correctly then use this code in your view.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border="1px solid black">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Created At</td>
        <td>Updated At</td>
        <td>Date of birth</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($student as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->updated_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->dob}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->gender}}</td>
        <td><a href="student/". $value->id>Show</a> | 
            <a href="student/" . $value->id ."/edit">Edit</a> |
            <form method="post" 
             action="/student/".$value->id."/delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="
                    {!!csrf_token() !!}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class=
                            "btn btn-warning">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: When I add `return $student`, it shows up empty array brackets. But, I already have 10 data in my DB

Comment: I have found the mistake. Thanks